# VBScript: Printing all characters in UTF-8

Tags: utf-8, vbscript

I'm writing a simple script to build a HTML page to check if all the characters in UTF-8 are being rendered properly:

```
Dim oStream : Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
oStream.Open
oStream.CharSet = "utf-8"

' Code writing out the top HTML snipped for brevity

Dim iChar
For iChar = 32 to 255
    oStream.WriteText iChar & " = " & Chr(iChar) & "<br/>" & VbCrLf
Next

' Code writing out the bottom HTML snipped for brevity

oStream.SaveToFile "page.html", 2
Set oStream = Nothing
```

This works great, until I try and print characters beyond 255 in which case I get the error: **Invalid procedure call or argument: 'Chr' (800A0005)**.

Can someone please explain how I can print all the characters within the UTF-8 character set?

The test is designed to see how the raw characters renders - so having a file with `&#256;` in it would not be a correct as it would need to print the actual Latin capital letter A with macron (Ā).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the `ChrW()` variant;

> [`ChrW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws6aa3sf%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) is provided for 32-bit platforms that use Unicode characters.
>   Its argument is a Unicode (wide) character code, thereby avoiding the
>   conversion from ANSI to Unicode.

Comment: Site note when converting from a character to unicode you can use the AscW(char)(instead of Asc(char) which returns ANSI